# How to submit the token in the FunCaptcha callback function?

Tags: selenium, twitter, bots, chromium, captcha

I'm trying to bypass the funCaptcha in Twitter Account Registration using selenium webDriver in C#. I'm using third party captcha solver for solving the captcha itself and as response I'm getting bypass token.

The problem that I currently have is that I can't locate the callback function that I need to call/submit, in order to pass the funCaptcha .

There is no form, there is no field to add it. I guess that there is some JS function attached to some html element (something like OnVerify or similar) that needs to be called and the solution token should be passed as parameter, but I have no luck finding it so far.

Did anyone knows how and where to locate the function?